# Lipschitz hypersurface

Tags: real-analysis, hypersurfaces

I asked this already on Math SE. Maybe this definition is not quite common, but I'm asking myself what a Lipschitz hypersurface is. Intuitively this is a hypersurface which can locally be parametrized by Lipschitz functions. I hope this intuition is correct.
Nevertheless I didn't find any precise definition. Does anybody know an exact definition of what a Lipschitz hyersurface is ?

Comment: This is one possible interpretation. Another is a hyper surface which is locally a Lipschitz graph. If you found this when reading a paper, I suggest you check the context and how this notion is used.

Comment: Thanks, isn't this the same, i.e. to say that it is locally parametrized by Lipschitz functions and a local Lipschitz graph ?